# Invalid JSON Primitive when using a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have code that makes an AJAX call to an MVC controller method and it'll work without a hitch if I do this:

```
var obj = '{"titlename":"whatever"}';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Titles/Yo",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: obj,
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#title_field").html(result.TitleName);
                }
            });
```

But if I do this:

```
var stringed="whatever"
            var obj = '{"titlename":stringed}';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Titles/Yo",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: obj,
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#title_field").html(result.TitleName);
                }
            });
```

It craps out on me with an "invalid JSON primitive" error. I keep trying various single and double quote permutations, but they all keep giving me the same error. How can I insert a string variable into a JSON object?

Comment: The value `obj` should not have quotes around it. It's an object, not  a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var stringed = "whatever";
var obj = '{"titlename": "' + stringed + '"}';
```

Also you may want to take a look at a JSON2 library, which can stringify your data automatically.

Comment: I tried every suggestion here and this was the only one that worked for me. Thanks, doodack.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you declaring your object as a String?

Have you tried doing:

```
var stringed="whatever";
var obj = {
   "titlename":stringed
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  var stringed="whatever";
   var obj = {"titlename": stringed};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Titles/Yo",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: obj,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#title_field").html(result.TitleName);
        }
    });
```

What you had was just a string that contained the the string "stringed", you need a object literal.

jQuery can take an object and it'll take care of sending the json string to the server instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = {"titlename":stringed};
```

This is probably what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
var stringed="whatever";
var obj_as_object = {titlename: stringed};
var obj_as_string = JSON.stringify(obj_as_object);

...
data: obj_as_string  //This goes in your ajax call
```

With this, we're auto encoding the obj with JSON.

`JSON.stringify` will work in modern browsers. If you want support to an older browser (for example, IE6) you should use a library such as json2 from http://json.org.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great way to do it but..

```
var stringed="whatever"
var obj = '{"titlename":'+stringed+'}';
```

Or

```
var obj = {
  "titlename":stringed
}
```